# Java - IntelliJ complains about missed semicolons, but I'm not sure anyways what's the issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've met a problem when I was doing an Udemy Java course. I've written the code below, because topic of lesson was methods. Hoverer, I've no clue why it can't be compiled. Could someone help me spot the error?

Here's the errors that IntelliJ gives me:

[image: List of errors]

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String playerName = "Piotr";

    int playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(1500);
    displayHighScorePosition("Piotr", playerPosition);

    playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(900);
    displayHighScorePosition("Cezary", playerPosition);

    playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(400);
    displayHighScorePosition("Adam", playerPosition);

    playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(50);
    displayHighScorePosition("Julia", playerPosition);

    private static void displayHighScorePosition(String playerName, int playerPosition) {
    System.out.println( playerName + " managed to get into " + playerPosition );

}

    private static int CalculateHighScorePosition(int playerScore) {
        if (playerScore > 1000) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (playerScore > 500 && playerScore < 1000) {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (playerScore > 100 && playerScore < 500) {
            return 3;
        }
        else {
            return 4;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I believe I spy an extra closing brace possibly.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this despite my better judgement.

You've defined two methods inside of your main method.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String playerName = "Piotr";

    int playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(1500);
    displayHighScorePosition("Piotr", playerPosition);

    playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(900);
    displayHighScorePosition("Cezary", playerPosition);

    playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(400);
    displayHighScorePosition("Adam", playerPosition);

    playerPosition = CalculateHighScorePosition(50);
    displayHighScorePosition("Julia", playerPosition);
  }

  private static void displayHighScorePosition(String playerName, int playerPosition) {
    System.out.println( playerName + " managed to get into " + playerPosition );
  }

  private static int CalculateHighScorePosition(int playerScore) {
    if (playerScore > 1000) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (playerScore > 500 && playerScore < 1000) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (playerScore > 100 && playerScore < 500) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 4;
    }
  }

}
```